# Flutter Customised Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I attain a customized container like this,
I have tried custom paint,stacks.everything , nothing seems to work

[image]

Comment: Please share the source code of your best attempt so far

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Comment: Maybe a Row with three children? One for the green background, one for the green/white part and one for the the white background? And set different flex to make the middle one take less space?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673135/9930734) on stackoverflow will give you an head start and it can be achieved using

> ClipPath

For better understanding of ClipPath here are some [Custom ClipPath example](https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/08/flutter-draw-custom-shaps-clip-path.html) and also guide to understanding [paths](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0) on the device screen.